# Disposing of Objects with long living dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, events, dispose

```
public class ABC
{
    public ABC(IEventableInstance dependency)
    {
        dependency.ANewEvent += MyEventHandler;
    }

    private void MyEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Do Stuff
    }
}
```

Let us say that an instance of ABC is a long living object and that my dependency is an even longer running object.  When an instance of ABC needs to be cleaned up, I have two options.

One I could have a Cleanup() method to unsubscribe from the ANewEvent event or I could implement IDisposable and in the Dispose unwire the event.  Now I have no control over whether the consumer will call the dispose method or even the Cleanup method should I go that route.

Should I implement a Finaliser and unsubscribe then?  It feels dirty but I do not want hanging instances of ABC around.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution to this, after leaving this question alone for a year, is that I should implement IDisposable and simply unsubscribe the event in my Dispose().

Since I'm not responsible for the lifetime of the dependency, it is not up to me to do anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

I read this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx):

> Because the Dispose method must be
>   called explicitly, objects that
>   implement IDisposable **must also
>   implement a finalizer to handle
>   freeing resources when Dispose is not
>   called**. By default, the garbage
>   collector automatically calls an
>   object's finalizer prior to reclaiming
>   its memory. However, once the Dispose
>   method has been called, it is
>   typically unnecessary for the garbage
>   collector to call the disposed
>   object's finalizer. To prevent
>   automatic finalization, Dispose
>   implementations can call the
>   GC.SuppressFinalize method.

So to be on the safe side in this case, I'd implement both IDisposable and a finalizer. And I agree, it's a bit dirty, but then again, that's the price you pay when dealing with long-lifespan objects.

Comment: However, a finaliser is only required if we're using unmanaged code.

Comment: @RayBooysen: The issue isn't whether one is using unmanaged code, but rather whether one is using things which require cleanup, and which can be usefully cleaned up in the context of a finalizer.  There are contexts entirely within managed code where finalizers are necessary for cleanup, but there are also many where even though failure to call `Dispose` will cause problems, a finalizer can't do anything to help (e.g. because there's no thread-safe cleanup method, or because cleanup would be required to detach a strong reference that would prevent the finalizer from running).